# How to Find all Pairs in an Array of Integers Whose sum is Equal to a Given Number

Tags: java

A selection is being made to the company, but I, apparently, failed him. But a separate task that I could not solve haunts me. And I want to understand where I was wrong and what the problem is.

**Conditions of the problem**
Given a positive integer "target". A sequence of positive integers is also given. It is necessary to write "1" in the output file if the sequence has two numbers, the sum of which is equal to the value of "target" or "0" if there are none.

**Input format**

5

1 7 3 4 7 9

**Output format**

1

**Notes**

All numbers used in the problem are in the range 0 < N < 999999999

Input file name: input.txt

Output file name: output.txt

Time Limit 1.5 seconds

Memory limit 64MB

My code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Sum {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        List<Integer> allNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            allNumbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }


        int target = allNumbers.get(0);
        allNumbers.remove(0);

        Integer [] myArray = allNumbers.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        printpairs(myArray, target);

    }

    static void printpairs(Integer arr[], int target) throws IOException { 

        HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
        int temp = 0;
        final int index = arr.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i) { 
            temp = target - arr[i]; 

            if (s.contains(temp)) {
                fos.write(Integer.toString(1).getBytes());
                break;
            } 

            s.add(arr[i]); 
        }

        if (!s.contains(temp)) {
            fos.write(Integer.toString(0).getBytes());
        }

    }
}
```

If I use Java 7x32 I go beyond the time limit, and if I use Java 8 I go beyond the memory limit
I also tried to solve through HashSet, but the problem remained the same.

another my variant

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sum {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> allNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            allNumbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

        }

        int target = allNumbers.get(0);
        allNumbers.remove(0);

        Integer[] array = allNumbers.toArray(new Integer[0]);

        try {
            printpairs(array, target);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public static void printpairs(Integer[] numbers, int target) throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");

        Arrays.sort(numbers);

        int left = 0;
        int right = numbers.length - 1;
        int sum = 0;

        while (left < right) {
            sum = numbers[left] + numbers[right];

            if (sum == target) {
                fos.write(Integer.toString(1).getBytes());
                fos.close();
                break;
            } else if (sum < target) {
                left = left + 1;

            } else if (sum > target) {
                right = right - 1;
            }
        }

        if (sum != target) {
            fos.write(Integer.toString(0).getBytes());
            fos.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: maybe using `short` instead of `Integer` would reduce the memory consumption in Java 8 enough?

Comment: If you hit the memory limit using `HashSet`, perhaps you could use a sorted `int[]`.

Comment: @AndyTurner oh, sorry, All numbers used in the problem are in the range 0 < N < 999999999

Answer (score 2):

This is a known way to simplify this kind of problem:

```
Set<Integer> sumtoTarget = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  Integer number = arr[i];

  if (number > target) { continue; }

  Integer diff = target - number;
  if (diff > 0) {
    if (sumToTarget.contains(diff) { 
      // found your pair diff + number
      return 1;
    } else {  // add to the set
      sumToTarget.add(diff); 
    }
  }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Java8 - 0.898s - 78.45Mb / Java 7 x32 - 1.585s - 24.91Mb

Comment: You can make it even faster by not pushing the input numbers to an array, but rather processing them right away.